# Entity Framework Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am trying to run a Dot Net MVC web application on windows 10 server.
The development environment configuration:

```
1. Visual Studio 2022, 
2. .Net Framework 4.8, 
3. EntityFramework 6.4.4,
4. MySql.Data.EntityFramework 8.3.0
```

My Connection string:

```
string connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=testDB;Uid=root;Pwd=Pasword1;port=3306;"
```

MyWebViewModel Class:

```
public class MyWebViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int WorkId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string Networkname { get; set; }
    public int PageId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string DataSource { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string SelectedContentType { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<DerviedContent> DerviedContent { get; set; }
}
```

The below code is throwing an exception:

```
List<MyWebViewModel> viewModel = null;  
viewModel = (from w in MyClass.GetApplicationDbContext().Pagelayout.AsEnumerable()
                 where w.WorkId == WorkId && w.PageId == PageId
                 orderby w.Sequence
                 select new MyWebViewModel
                 {
                     Id = w.Id,
                     Name = w.Name,
                     Content = w.Content,
                     Type = w.Type,
                     WorkId = w.WorkId,
                     PageId = w.PageId
                 }).ToList();
```

Exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.EFMySqlDataReader.ChangeType(Object sourceValue, Type targetType)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.EFMySqlDataReader.GetValue(Int32 ordinal)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

For testing, I replaced the Entity Framework code with below and its working:

```
var v = connection.Query<MyWebViewModel>(@"SELECT Id, Name, Content, Type,  WorkId, 
PageId FROM LayoutViewModelTable where WorkId =11 and PageId = 11");
List<MyWebViewModel> viewModel= v.ToList();
```

The project was originally built using .Net Framework 4.5 and MySQL Server 5.3.

I found lot of suggestion about updating the Entity Framework version etc. but there is no luck. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please show the definition of `MyWebViewModel`.

Comment: Sorry, Included MyWebViewModel class in the question

Comment: Looks like we also need the definition of the `Pagelayout` entity type, whatever that is. The exception message pertains to whatever property is being populated on that type.

Comment: Incidentally, you're using `Pagelayout.AsEnumerable()` which is causing the whole table to be retrieved, and then the `where` and `orderby` are being done client-side. Remove `.AsEnumerable()`

Comment: At this point it looks like some type in MySql is not loading into model that represents `Pagelayout`. Potencially, you can add specific data type attribute or use `NotMappedAttribute`. Or delete property altogether,

Comment: I deleted unused properties and created a new class for testing, but it still not working.